# SharePoint Designer 2010 Error: Could not find the webserver at "Host Name" on port 80

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, port

I am trying to open a SharePoint website "http://qasite.organization.com/SharepointSite/". But I am getting the following error in Sharepoint Designer as follows,

```
Could not find a web server at "http://qasite.organization.com/" port 80. Please check to make sure that the web server name is valid and your proxy settings are set correctly. If you are sure that everything is correct, the web server may be temporarily unavailable.
```

But the web server http://qasite.organization.com/ is available. Other sites on the server are working fine. After clicking "OK" button on the alert box, another message appears as,

```
An error occured while trying to fetch data from your sharepoint site. Unexpected response from server. The content type of the response is "". The status is "OK".
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Make sure you are using the default zone address, not any other zones.

Answer (score 1):

Try following steps if they help

- Go to your Central Administration website
- General Application Settings > SharePoint Designer.
- Select the web application that is hosting your site  collection and verify that SharePoint Designer is enabled.

OR

There can be an issue when there are web applications in farm that have more than one binding in IIS.  When there is more than one, the site  can't be opened.  To get around this, you will have extended my web application to a new URL (host header) and used that URL to connect with SPD2010.

Also [Check](http://skurocks.wordpress.com/2009/06/26/enable-client-integration-user-permissions-for-web-application-%E2%80%93-caution/) if Client Integration is enabled.

[Source](http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/cant-open-sharepoint-site-sharepoint-62397.aspx)