# Can not CheckOut ,edit and open master pages,Page Layouts in share point 2013 designer

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer

using share point designer 2013 i can not open master page and edit master page all the settings for share point designer allowed for web application level.

SharePoint Farm has 2 WFE Servers Web Application created on Port 81 Web Application URL: First WFE Server name & Port: http://spTestWfe1:81 Port 81 is allowed from my PCto WFE

when i try to edit master pages or page layouts below is the message from SPD
[image]

could not find a webserver at '' on port 81. please check to make sure that the web server name is valid and your proxy settings are set correctly sharepoint designer

Answer (score 0):

Here're some tips for you to troubleshooting the issue.

1.Go to central administration -> Manage web applications -> Select the web application -> Authentication Providers -> Under Zone, click Default to open the Edit Authentication page -> Set Enable Client Integration as Yes.

2.Check whether use default zone in the AAM.

Similar questions:

[SharePoint Designer Error: Could not find the webserver at “Host Name” on port 80](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60333/sharepoint-designer-2010-error-could-not-find-the-webserver-at-host-name-on-p)

[Problems opening a site in Designer with a friendly URL](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/2c5f15d5-3110-485d-b424-8805d3196462/problems-opening-a-site-in-designer-with-a-friendly-url?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy)